# URL for the Artist page or search page of App Store?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am creating an iPhone game. I want to have a button in my game that takes people to the other games by me. I get the URL from the iTunes (copy URL) like this:

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewArtist?id=307450671

But when I open this URL in iphone, it take me to the iTunes, not App Store.
and I also tried http://phobos...., not working too.

Any ideas? What is the URL Scheme for the artist page or search page of app store?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, I get that link:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?submit=seeAllLockups&media=software&entity=software&term=CloudWonder"]];

replace the term with my search keyword will get it work.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to make a link to your company like this:

http://itunes.com/MyCompanyName

At least I know it works for me:

http://itunes.com/Rebisoft

You can do something similar for apps:

http://itunes.com/app/Scribattle

Comment: This solution is better than zhongshu's one, as http://itunes.com/MyCompanyName will only display the apps from "MyCompanyName" and not those from companies whose name contains "MyCompanyName" (that would be the result of zhongshu's solution).